# Is it possible to importKey from a gpg file which is expired?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I am trying to validate whether a gpg file got expired or not.
As first step I am trying to get the key of the file using node **gpg** package
Method: gpg.importKey

As response I am getting error as below

"Error","message":"gpg: invalid armor header

I tried the same for gpg files which is not gona expire for now. Able to get Key in such case.

My question is,

1. Since the file got expired, gpg.importKey is sending error ?
2. Any other way to validate the file expiry ?

Comment: Assuming you mean the nodejs/npm package gpg, which runs gpg, that absolutely can import expired key(s). Note a _file_ can contain many keys, usually at least 2, so one file could contain a mixture of expired and unexpired keys, as well as keys invalid for other reasons like revocation or incompatibility. 'invalid armor' has nothing to do with expiration and means something else is wrong in the file, but since you don't show or describe it there is no clue what.. Look at file, identify how it doesn't meet the specifications in rfc4880 6.2, and fix it or replace it.

Comment: (To be clear, PGP _files_ are standardized and not specific to gpg, although creating files from gpg or using files in gpg are specific to gpg.)